# what are huge files 0.000001 and 0.000002 files and so on, in mysql data folder

Tags: mysql

In mysql data folder, I see some 0.000... files:

[image]

This is my `my.ini`:

```
[client]
host= .
port= 3306
socket= "MySQL"

[mysql]
no-auto-rehash


[mysqld]

max_allowed_packet = 800M
thread_concurrency = 8
skip-external-locking
port=3306
basedir="c:/zpanel/bin/mysql/"
datadir="e:/hafez/bin/mysql/mysql5.5.24/data/"
character-set-server=utf8
default-storage-engine=MYISAM
max_connections=200
query_cache_size = 128M
table_cache=256
tmp_table_size=256M
thread_cache_size=8
myisam_max_sort_file_size=32G
myisam_sort_buffer_size=205M
key_buffer_size = 384M
read_buffer_size = 2M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 8M
sort_buffer_size = 2M




innodb_fast_shutdown=0
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 16M
innodb_log_buffer_size = 8M
innodb_buffer_pool_size=1800MB
innodb_log_file_size = 256M
innodb_thread_concurrency = 16
innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 120
innodb_file_per_table 

innodb_doublewrite = 0
#log-bin = 0
innodb_support_xa = 0
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 0


tmpdir= "e:/hafez/bin/mysql/mysql5.5.24/tmp/"

enable-named-pipe
skip-federated
server-id = 1

default-time-zone   = "SYSTEM"
log_error           = "c:/zpanel/logs/mysql/mysql.err"
pid_file            = "mysql.pid"
general_log         = 0
general_log_file    = "c:/zpanel/logs/mysql/mysql.log"
slow_query_log      = 0
slow_query_log_file = "c:/zpanel/logs/mysql/mysql-slow.log"


[myisamchk]
key_buffer_size = 1024M
sort_buffer_size = 1024M
read_buffer = 8M
write_buffer = 8M

[mysqldump]
quick
max_allowed_packet = 16M

[mysqlhotcopy]
interactive-timeout
```

I recently added some innodb tables and these files **appeared**!

These files are in root mysql data folder(`e:/hafez/bin/mysql/mysql5.5.24/data`) and aren't in any database folder.

What are these files?

Is it safe to remove them?

Comment: they are binary log files. do not naively delete before you google for more info.

Comment: do not delete anything you know what it is

Comment: @JanDvorak wouldn't it be "you don't know what it is for" ?

Comment: @Prix both are valid syntactically and semantically (unless neither is). Mine is about identity, yours is about purpose.

Comment: @JanDvorak the way you said it he would delete all those files as he doesn't know what they are. Keep in mind not everyone on SO have a good understanding of English.

Comment: @Prix oops, I've dropped "unless" accidentally. Thanks for noticing.

Comment: instead of discuss, solve my problem!

Comment: I have the answer. I just need the question reopened...

Comment: @EmRa228 if I could, I would. Stick to "don't delete them" for now. Also, Chris has already shown a purpose. don't be rude.

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA it is reopened

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA upvoted it for reopen for u ;)

Comment: Somebody just crossposted this in DBA StackExchange: http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/45476/877 and said pretty much the same thing.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it was cross-posted elsewhere

Comment: @AndrewBarber, Actually it's perfectly on topic, even while it may be a cross-site duplicate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am absolutely sure those are binary logs.

Look back at the my.ini

```
innodb_doublewrite = 0
#log-bin = 0
innodb_support_xa = 0
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 0
```

When `log-bin` was uncommented and mysql started, the binary logs were prefixed with `0`

When commented out and mysql restarted, binary logs were no longer written.

Verify the mysql's state on this by running:

```
SHOW BINARY LOGS;
```

You will either get

- an error stating binary logging is not enabled.
- you will get the list of binary logs

If binary logging is off, it is safe to delete.

If binary logging is still on, restart mysql, then delete them.

Give it a Try !!!